# Modifying class instances in Python

Tags: class, python-3.x, shelve

I have a small class:

```
import pickle
import shelve

class Base:

    def __init__(self, userid, username, pic_list=[]):
        self.userid=userid
        self.pic_list=pic_list
        self.username_list=[username]
        self.username=self.username_list[-1]

    def pic_add(self, pic):
        self.pic_list.append(pic)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    path="D:/"

    db = shelve.open(path+'test_base')

    db['111']=Base('111','111name',[4,5,6])
    db['111'].pic_add('123dsf')

    print (sorted(db['111'].pic_list))

    db.close()
```

I want to append `123dsf` to `pic_list` of class instance "111". But the result I get is:

```
[4, 5, 6]
[Finished in 0.3s]
```

I want to receive [4, 5, 6, 123dsf]. What am I doing wrong?

Thanx.

P.S. Hint -  It is something with shelve module syntax, 'cos adding 'y' works fine:

```
db['111']=Base('111','111name',[4,5,6])
db['111'].pic_add('123dsf')
Base.pic_add(db['111'],'123dsf')

y=Base('222','222name',[7,8,9])
y.pic_add('pis')

print (y.pic_list)

print (sorted(db['111'].pic_list))
```

The result is:

```
[7, 8, 9, 'pis']
[4, 5, 6]
[Finished in 0.4s]
```

Comment: Have you tried `db = shelve.open(path+'test_base', writeback=True)` as proposed in the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html#shelve-example

Comment: Thanx - your answer and link are greatly helpful, please - make answer out of it - I'll confirm it.

Comment: Glad I could help. Posted an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways to do it - as proposed in the documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html#shelve-example

**1.** set `writeback` flag:

```
db = shelve.open(path+'test_base', writeback=True)
```

allows you mutate objects in place:

```
db['111'].pic_add('123dsf')
```

**2.** Retrieve copy of stored object, then mutate copy, then store copy back:

```
cpy = db['111']
cpy.pic_add('123dsf')
db['111'] = cpy
```